# How can I measure the server utilization?

Tags: cpu-usage

How can I measure the server utilization in terms of **requests per unit of time** (lets say one hour), assuming the server's maximum capacity is known (for example, 1000 requests per hour)? 
I know the equation will be:

```
utilization = Number of executed requests by server / server capacity
```

But how can I measure the requests sent from a client to a server?
I need a valid equation to define a request please.

Comment: What kind of requests are these?  What software is handling the requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered as "request" in a client/server model cannot be identified without knowing the protocol. To illustrate, multiple HTTP requests can be sent in one connection. UDP based protocols do not use connections at all.

Most general description I can come up with to define a request in an unidentified client/server protocol is the number of messages initiated by the client that require a response by the server. It is a observed variable, not a derivative.

In a program you would obtain this variable via a callback or RPC to the server in question or a program that would be able to provide this variable by inspecting logfiles.

Comment: file requestes to any type of server(for example: web server)

Comment: I need a general formula to define a request

Comment: I just need to measure the utilization of a server

Answer (score 0):

For utilisation you can get all you need from the "sar" utility.

However "request" will be very specific to the software you are running. For instance if you are running Apache web server, by default, it will log each request and you can scan these logs to extract you request data.

However be aware that these are "technical" requests and may not conform to your users idea of a request. Think Amazon, I may think of my book order as one "request", Amazons server will log this as 50 or so http requests.

Comment: I have another question, How can I estimate the number of jobs executed by a CPU during one hour ?